# How to make modal scrollable vertically?

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal

I have created a modal using Aura and LWC. I need to make it scrollable vertically. I added the following tag `<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium slds-scrollable_y" id="modal-content-id-1">` but it is not working. Can you help me implement it?

TIA.

Here is my modal:

```
 <template>

    <header class="slds-modal__header">
        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Convert Lead</h2>        
    </header>



       <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium slds-scrollable_y" id="modal-content-id-1">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slds-modal__container{
    max-width: 70rem !important;
    width:80% !important;
    height:40% !important;
    max-height:50% !important;   
}
```

Comment: Set the `height `or `max-height` to the div with the scrollable class.

Comment: Hi @rahulgawale thanks for your reply, can you help me set the height. I created a CSS file but it is not working. I posted the code I have.  Sorry I am new to LWC and in web development

Comment: try `height:40vh` or `max-height:50vh` in css